# Ionic / Angular - Refresh articles on app resume

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have developed a News App using Ionic / Angular. Here is the code for the News Tab:

```
<ion-view view-title="News">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <ion-refresher pulling-text="Actualizează articolele" on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>
      <a class="article" ng-repeat="article in articles" href="#/tab/news/{{article.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{article.image}}" class="article-image">
        <h2 class="article-title">{{article.title}}</h2>
        <p class="article-published">{{article.published}}</p>
        <p class="article-intro">{{article.intro}}...</p>
      </a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here is the controller:

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, Articles) {
  Articles.all().then(function(articles) {
    $scope.articles = articles
  });
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    Articles.all().then(function(articles) {
      $scope.articles = articles
    });
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  };
})
```

`$scope.articles = articles` reads the articles from an external JSON file.

So I have the pull to refresh option working but there is one problem. **If a user keeps the app open in the background I would like the articles to be refreshed when the user opens the app again.** Someone can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution is using the cordova [`resume` event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume) and fire your refresh callback when it gets triggered. You can define this by using the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

However, a better approach is to use the `$ionicPlatform` service.

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, Articles, $ionicPlatform) {

  $ionicPlatform.on('resume', $scope.doRefresh);

  Articles.all().then(function(articles) {
    $scope.articles = articles
  });

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    Articles.all().then(function(articles) {
      $scope.articles = articles
    });
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  };

})
```

Also, another approach is to broadcast on the root scope to avoid breaking the angular way inside a controller.

```
app.module('myApp',[])
    .run(function ($rootScope) {

        document.addEventListener("resume", function () {        
            $rootScope.$broadcast('onAppResume');        
        }, false);        
    });
```

Then you can listen to this event from your controllers:

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, Articles) {

  $scope.$on('onAppResume', $scope.doRefresh);

  Articles.all().then(function(articles) {
    $scope.articles = articles
  });

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    Articles.all().then(function(articles) {
      $scope.articles = articles
    });
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  };

})
```